# Does the definition of a local variable will low down the performance of the app?

Tags: java

Take the following code snap for example:

```
public int demoMethod(){
    SomeClass object= getItFromSomewhere();
    return object.getResult();
}
```

also we can directly return `getItFromSomewhere().getResult()`. My question is whether the definition of "object" will low  down the performance? And in some case, maybe the temporary local variable is very complicated, such as

```
SomeClass object =  otherClassObject.getMethod1().getMethod2().getMethod3().getMethod4();
return object.getMethod5();
```

If I don't use the temporary "object", the statement will be very difficult to read, how about you guys deal with this case?

Comment: even if it would slow down, it would slow that little that you would never notice it

Comment: No, it's not going to slow things down.  Don't worry about it.

Comment: Could you tell me more about the reason? Or where I can find the reason? Because I want to surely solve my question.

Comment: It will allocate memory, GC will get some work but performance should be stable.

Comment: Why should it allocate memory?

Answer (score 2):

Afaik will be completely removed by jit. So there should not be any impact on performance introducing additional local variables to simplify expressions.

PS: The long expression, a.d.b.c is called a 'train wreck' by uncle bob. They are hard to read and a PITA to debug when you get an exception like a NPE.

Answer (score 1):

As a general rule (in my opinion, but I trust I am not alone), your code should be optimized for **readability** before any other kind of optimization. This will allow other programmers to improve it later on, if needed. A very fast but unreadable code quickly becomes useless as nobody is able to make changes to it. Also, trust the compilers (javac and the JIT): they know how to rewrite your code to remove unused statements, like a variable that is not actually necessary.

Then, if speed is an issue, you should try to improve it by choosing more appropriate data structures (especially containers) and algorithms.

Lastly, *if speed is still an issue* (very rare nowadays), you should seek the advice of a specialist. There are people who [do wonders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926266/performance-optimization-strategies-of-last-resort) with code that is seemingly efficient to begin with, but this is not something the average developer should do on a daily basis.